# Docs Add-on Project OAuth Scopes - Unable to locate scopes to request verification

Tags: google-apps-script, scope, google-oauth, verification

New users for Google Docs Add-on get the message: "This app isn't verified."

I've requested and have been approved for the following scopes.

```
email 
profile 
openid 
../auth/drive.appdata 
../auth/drive.file
```

I need approval for these scopes as my project automatically added them:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
```

I cannot locate these in the "Add scope" area. What APIs would I need to activate to get these scopes, or what process do I need to go through?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to add the Docs API and Scripts API.

Then I was able to add the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
scope and also I added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/scripts scope.

Google had me make a youtube video showing what the add-on was and how the roles were used.

Then the add-on was approved.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem I'm running into - the team doing the verification process has not been helpful with better instructions :) I just added the Slides API and Scripts API for my add-on, but I'm still not seeing the scopes they need me to add (/auth/script.container.ui and /auth/script.external_request). Did you find those two scopes in the consent screen modal after you added Scripts API?

Comment: Oh, I might've figured it out: there's an option to "manually add" scopes at the bottom of that screen. Let's see if this works...

Comment: Yeah, strangely they approved the addon without the /auth/script.container.ui and /auth/script.external_requests the first time, but when I updated it they didn't. I just manually added those scopes. We'll see how it goes.